# API no longer connecting

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask, python-requests, flask-restful

**Project**: I'm building a restful API that's taking data from one API and using another API to translate part of that data, the description, into some other lexicon.

**Problem**: All was working fine until a few days back I stopped getting connection with the translation API. I've changed nothing in the code relating to the request. I can also replicate the problem when I use VCS to go back to earlier versions of my code. I've tried this in two different environments but I encounter the same issue. I've also tried my web browser and *POSTMAN* but they seem to be getting the appropriate responses.
I'm a receiving a HTTP code of 200 when I when running a test file but not getting the response I want from the translation API.

**Code explanation**: So I'm taking some nested information, `flavor_text_entries` from my first API (data) and using that as my description, setting that as a variable and sending it to my translation API to translate and return only the translation of the description.

```
def extract_descriptive_text(json_blob, language='en', version='sword'):
    text = ""
    for f in json_blob['flavor_text_entries']:
        if f['language']['name'] == language and f['version']['name'] == version:
            text = f['flavor_text'] 
    return text


def extract_useful_info(translated):
    text = []
    wanted_info = translated['contents']['translated']
    text.append(wanted_info)
    return text


@app.route('/pokemon/<string:name>/', methods=['GET'])
def get_translation(name):
    descrip_url = f"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/{name}"
    r = requests.get(descrip_url)
    json_blob = r.json()
    text_trans = extract_descriptive_text(json_blob)
    trans_url = f"https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/shakespeare.json?text={text_trans}"
    shakespeare = requests.get(trans_url)
    translated = shakespeare.json()
    useful_info = extract_useful_info(translated)
    return jsonify({'name': name, 'description': useful_info})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Error** I get when I try to return everything from translation API:

```
ERROR:
{
  "name": "charizard", 
  "description": {
    "error": {
      "code": 404, 
      "message": "Not Found"
    }
  }
}
```

**Traceback** I receive when I try return just the translation:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/swapneel/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/swapneel/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/swapneel/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 272, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/Users/swapneel/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/swapneel/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/swapneel/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/swapneel/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/swapneel/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 272, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/Users/swapneel/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/swapneel/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/swapneel/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/swapneel/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/swapneel/Desktop/projects/foobar/main.py", line 58, in get_translation
    useful_info = extract_useful_info(translated)
  File "/Users/swapneel/Desktop/projects/foobar/main.py", line 21, in extract_useful_info
    wanted_info = translated['contents']['translated']
KeyError: 'contents'
```

**Libraries and Packages** used:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Api
import requests
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The translation API can't find the search term `charizard` and is returning a different JSON then the one you are expecting and are able to handle.

In `extract_useful_info()` you are retrieving `translated['contents']` but as you can see in the API response you are getting that key is not present when there's an API error. Instead, the response contains `'name'` and `'description'`.

You'll need to implement a check for when the API errors out. You can do that by e.g. wrapping `wanted_info` in a `try/except`:

```py
def extract_useful_info(translated):
    text = []
    try:
        wanted_info = translated['contents']['translated']
    except KeyError:
        wanted_info = ''

    text.append(wanted_info)
    return text
```

As a side note: I can't see why `text` needs to be a list. The code becomes much simpler if it's just a string i.e.

```py
def extract_useful_info(translated):
    try:
        return translated['contents']['translated']
    except KeyError:
        return '' # return None is better but I don't know if your app can handle that.
```

If that's the case, though, we we can get rid of `extract_useful_info()` altogether and do

```py
...
try: 
    useful_info = shakespeare.json()['contents']['translated']
except KeyError:
    useful_info = '' # or return None
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Simeon. 
So what my concern has to do with is the fact that I am not getting the info I was getting before from that translation API. I can get all the information I want from the PokeAPI, I test it regularly. But when I put this data into the translation URL as per this line of code :
`text_trans = extract_descriptive_text(json_blob)
trans_url = f"https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/shakespeare.json?text={text_trans}"`
I get nothing back where before I got a translation back. I have not changed this code since it actually responded with a translation

Comment: There are two possibilities: either the API changed its response or you are using a different search term. Did you use ‘charizard’ before? Regardless, you’ll have to update your code to prevent it from crashing as it does now.

Comment: Everything is the same as before. It actually started working again after I posted this with no code change bar the try, except error handling. It's now not been working for 2 days  with no code change relating to that particular part

Comment: Just to clarify: it worked for a while with the try/except and stopped working again? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, it worked under both conditions. It's always the KeyError message I receive where it can't find the 'contents' key in my response